# System.NullReferenceException error installing user-secret

Tags: iis, model-view-controller, web-applications, visual-studio-2015, secret-manager

i have followed the instruction in previous posts but still cannot get user-secret to work. 
I'm trying to install it on my IIS server. I run everything in this path:
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\wwwroot>

> dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-update1 -p
>
> dnu commands install Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager --overwrite

the installation passes and I get the message:

> The following commands were installed: user-secret

but them when i run:

> user-secret -h

I get the following error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Microsoft.Framework.SecretManager.CommandOutputProvider..ctor(IRuntimeEnvi
>   ronment runtimeEnv)
>      at Microsoft.Framework.SecretManager.Program..ctor(IRuntimeEnvironment runtim
>   eEnv)

needless to say - no UserSecrets folder is created...

can you help? 
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just try to restart Visual Studio and Developer Command Prompt for VS2015.
It worked for me.

1. dnx v. 1.0.0-rc1-final
2. Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager v. 1.0.0-rc1-final